# Calculate list of first derivative of function in Maxima for selected interval

Tags: maxima

I am facing a simple problem in Maxima: I want to calculate list of first derivatives of function / expression in various points. I know how to calculate list of "points" for normal expression:

```
float(makelist((x^2/sin(x-x/2),x,1,1000))
```

but when I run the expression through *diff* it changes expression to function and I don't know how to work with functions. I tried:

```
float(makelist(diff(x^2/sin(x-x/2)),x,1,1000))
```

which "zeroed" on me. Then I tried this:

```
float(makelist(''(diff(x^2)),x,1,1000))
```

which gives you right answer, but the result is not a number anymore. It's a list of something like:

```
[2.0 del(1.0), 4.0 del(2.0), 6.0 del(3.0), 8.0 del(4.0), ...
```

Would someone care to enlighten me about Maxima functions and numeric evaluation?

I know that this is a silly beginner's question, but I have never worked with Maxima before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `float(makelist(''(diff(x^2, x)),x,1,1000))` i.e. you need to write `diff(expression, variable)` instead of just `diff(expression)`.

Comment: Thank you, you are my savior. :-)